# Is there an effcient way to perform search query in django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, search

I'm creating a blog in which i want to perform a search query based on ones rating (1-5). Here my search would be like query:"smart phone tech updates", rating:"3". Result should be list of post that contains query word(at least one word) which has rating 3, in a sorted way on val(for each query word, if found in title val+=1 if found in content val+=0.4).

My models.py file has the following :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    enter code here
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My view.py file has the following:

```
def search(request):
    contents = Post.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET['query']
        rating = request.GET['rating']

        # search function

        # contents = InSearch.search_fun(contents,query,rating)
        vector = SearchVector('title', weight='A') + SearchVector('content', weight='B')
        qry = SearchQuery(str(query))
        contents = Post.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, qry)).order_by('-rank')

        #print("---->\n\t"+query+ str(contents))

        context = {
            'contents': contents
        }
    else:
        context = {
            'contents': Post.objects.all()
        }

    return render(request, 'feed/home.html', context)
```

My urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #...
    path('feed/search-result/', views.search, name='feed_search'),
]
```

I'm getting this error
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: plainto_tsquery`

Comment: Why are you trying to use Postgres functions in sqlite?

Comment: i found that search query in Django docs. As you said it is postgers db function and i'm using sqlite. Is there a way to get what i want through django models or sqlite query

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this in your views for searching.

```
from django.db.models import Q
def search(request):
 q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
       search_results = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=q)|Q(rating=q))
   # if you want the exact then do Post.objects.filter(Q(title__iexact=q) & Q(rating=q))

       return render(request, 'feed/home.html','search_results':search_results)
    else:
        messages.info(request,'no results found for {}',format(q))
```

If you want to sort search query result by number of matches then you can try like this:

```
search_results = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=q)|Q(rating=q)).annotate(title_counts=Count('title')).order_by('-title_counts')
```

And in your template give `name='q'` in the search form.

```
 <form  action="{% url 'your search action' %}">
     <input type="text" name="q">
     <input type='submit' value='Search'>
   </form>
```

Comment: Almost, but `rating` is an IntegerField and won't support `icontains`. Just `Q(title__icontains=q)|Q(rating=q)` would work.

Comment: this is not what i'm asking. your answer returns complete matching of query.

Comment: as of the question if i search "smart phone tech updates" it will return only row that has post or title that contains "smart phone tech updates" in same order. but not post that has smart or phone or tech or ... and also it don't sort the data nor return added value field to sort explicitly.

Comment: how do you want to sort the data?.If you want the exact result then you can do `title__iexact=q`

Comment: i want to sort result that has maximum matching.

Comment: consider there are titles of post post1: update iphone, post2: smart phone tech updates, post3: job offer, post4:smart world post5: tech gaint smart loader; result should be post2, post5, post1, post 4